# recaptcha always returns false

Tags: php, recaptcha

Im having a issue with my recaptcha. The problem is that it always returns false meaning it says the captcha failed. even when the right word is typed in.

Everything is up to date, using the latest library and triple checked the code and public/private key.

Issue I believe lies here....

```
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
          $privatekey = "************************************";
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                    $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                    $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                    $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
                  $error_string .= '<center>The reCAPTCHA wasnt entered correctly. Go back and try it again.</center><br />';
        }
```

I followed this example so I can't see what is going wrong. Been at it for days!

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php

CLient Code:

```
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    $publickey = "**********************"; // you got this from the signup page
    echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
```

carried out a var dump on the $resp variable and got this

```
object(ReCaptchaResponse)#2 (2) { ["is_valid"]=> bool(false) ["error"]=> string(21) "incorrect-captcha-sol" }
```

also did a `var_dump` recaptcha response field and got:

```
NULL
```

var dump post...

```
array(7) { ["user"]=> string(0) "" ["pass1"]=> string(0) "" ["pass2"]=> string(0) "" ["email"]=> string(0) "" ["email2"]=> string(0) "" ["gender"]=> string(4) "Male" ["register"]=> string(8) "register" }
```

var dump request...

```
array(10) { ["user"]=> string(0) "" ["pass1"]=> string(0) "" ["pass2"]=> string(0) "" ["email"]=> string(0) "" ["email2"]=> string(0) "" ["gender"]=> string(4) "Male" ["register"]=> string(8) "register" ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) "4e79u2fdgrrufvb79einufcmq6" ["cprelogin"]=> string(2) "no" ["cpsession"]=> string(65) ":fX5Z1aWfbsgjGfgb3b3J7koo3Y58y5ntgM6k8GTdrQ4YAcqaywAKnD7PRiayfXv3" }
```

Comment: check you really getting value `recaptcha_response_field` in `$_POST` ?

Comment: sorry? Didnt quite understand that. From what I did get. Both the form and this variable are both POST.

Comment: Whats the result of your var_dump($_POST); and the var_dump($_REQUEST); ?

Comment: Can we see the client side code that's posting to this page?

Comment: Have you enabled cookies in your browser? Does `session_start()` perhaps need to be called with this library as well? (or are these things not necessary with this library)?

Comment: cookies are enabled. with sessionstart it doesnt say anything about including that. its on a register page so your not really signing in from there.

Comment: @Bobski If you aren't sure with var_duno, put `var_dump($_POST);` and `var_dump($_REQUEST);` into your code and tell us what the output is.

Comment: ok added in original post. thanks

Comment: I have used it and it worked in first attempt like a charm. You the same code provided by the captacha help page, and see if all the keys are set properly. In btn, there are 2 types of keys-- single use and multi - site use.. Be sure about what keys you are using..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your support guys. I found the issue so decided to post if anyone comes across this problem in the future.

My form was inside my table, like

```
<table><form>...</form></table>
```

Apparently the form should be first then table!

Comment: Please click the checkmark icon on the left to accept your own answer so that this isn't listed as an unanswered question.